# g++ compiler cannot find file cstudio. What's wrong?

Tags: c++

I'm using windows 7 and have installed the GCC compiler.

I am compiling a C++ program using the following command:

> g++ convert.cpp -o convert.exe

But I am getting the following error:

> convert.cpp:1:19: fatal error: cstudio: No such file or directory
>   compilation terminated.

Why is that?

Comment: use cstdio instead of cstudio

Comment: @Varunkrishna As a general rule, when asking a question about a compile-time error, it's a good idea to post the code that's causing the error.

Answer (score 4):

There is no standard header called `<cstudio>`. There is one `<cstdio>`, though. Maybe that's what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message indicates, your compiler cannot find the file `cstudio`.

Remove (or fix) the matching `#include` to fix the problem.

As suggested by Benoit, you probably meant : `#include <cstdio>` instead of `#include <cstudio>` but unfortunately we can't tell without seeing some code.